# How to split PHP string if character count is greater

Tags: php, count, explode

I have a user input field. It will be a `textarea`. When user submit the form I want to check if the entered character count is more than 10. If more than 10 I want to split it. Clearly says, if I get a string

```
$someWords = "Pleasedon'tblowmetopiecesandthis will be a 12345 random.";
```

Then I want to split this string. Each parts should be maximum of 10 character long. Required result (clean text) should be something like below,

```
tblowmetop
iecesandth
is will be
 a 12345 r
 andom
```

How can I do this in PHP? I have idea about getting count using `strlen($string);`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: I have a column which accepts only values less than 10 character. So I need to add as small parts of 10 characters or less.

Comment: why not alter the table/column?

Comment: No. I want it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = "Hello Friend";

$arr1 = str_split($str);
$arr2 = str_split($str, 3);

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);

?>
```

This function counts space(" ") as one character
Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] =>
    [6] => F
    [7] => r
    [8] => i
    [9] => e
    [10] => n
    [11] => d
)

Array
(
    [0] => Hel
    [1] => lo
    [2] => Fri
    [3] => end
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Check this link for more information

Need to remove space use **str_replace** function before **str_split** for replace space in string

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHPs built-in function [`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php):

```
$chunkedString = chunk_split($someWords, 10);
```

This gives you a string with a line break after each 10 characters.

If you like to get an array with entries of 10 characters each you can use PHPs [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
$chunks = str_split($someWords, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but it output as one string. Below answer works. Thanks for your effort

Comment: You asked for one string. But I added the use of `str_split()` now to get an array of 10 character long sub-strings.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built-in function called [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) That splits a string and creates an array.

```
$arr = str_split($someWords, 10);
```

This code will create an array of strings, each with a length of 10 characters. The similar function [`chunk_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) can be used to insert additional content every n characters.

```
$chunked = chunk_split($someWords, 10);
```

`$chunked` is a **single string** with newlines inserted every 10 characters. This function can be useful for wrapping text for output.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using recursively

```
function submystr_to_array($str, $length, $arr_result = array() )
{
    $istr_len = strlen($str);

    if ( $istr_len == 0 )
        return $arr_result;

    $result = substr($str, 0, $length);
    $tail = substr($str, $length, $istr_len );

    if ( $result )
        array_push( $arr_result, $result );

    if( !$tail )
        return $arr_result;

    return submystr_to_array( $tail, $length, $arr_result);
}

$mystr = "Pleasedon'tblowmetopiecesandthis will be a 12345 random.";

var_dump( submystr_to_array($mystr, 10) );
```

result:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Pleasedon'"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "tblowmetop"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "iecesandth"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "is will be"
  [4]=>
  string(10) " a 12345 r"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "andom."
}
```